# Kann man die Verben »müssen« und »sollen« in einem Nebensatz gemeinsam benutzen?

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb

Kann man die Verben *müssen* und *sollen* in einem Nebensatz gemeinsam benutzen?
Wie sieht es im folgenden Satz aus?

> Wir möchten uns entschuldigen, weil wir den Artikel vor dem Versand
>   überprüfen *müssen sollten*.
>   (We want to apologize, because *we should have inspected* the item before shipping it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der richtige Satz für diesen Fall wäre:

> Wir möchten uns entschuldigen, weil wir den Artikel vor dem Versand
>   hätten überprüfen sollen.

*hätten* und *überprüfen* kann man hier auch vertauschen, und in beiden Fällen ließe sich *sollen* durch *müssen* ersetzen, ohne dass der Satz seine Gültigkeit verlöre. Der Beispielsatz aus der Frage ist aufgrund der Kombination »müssen sollten« allerdings falsch.

Ob *sollen* und *müssen* im gleichen Nebensatz auftreten können? Ja, dürfte aber eher selten vorkommen.

Findet ein Korrekturleser einen Fehler, könnte er beispielsweise sagen:

> Alles gut? Leider nein, weil es hier *müssen* heißen sollte und nicht *dürfen*.

Anderes Beispiel:

> Wir alle wollen fleißig sein, aber vor acht Uhr sollte niemand aufstehen müssen.

Ein bemerkenswertes Beispiel nennt auch @jonathan.scholbach in seinem Kommentar, mit einem einleitenden *denn* leicht in einen Nebensatz umzuwandeln.

Comment: Tadellos! Ich habe über das Verb _hätten_ vergessen. Jetzt sieht alles ja logisch aus! Danke.

Comment: Another possibility for "müssen" and "sollen" in one sentence. "Alle sollten gleich viel Steuern zahlen müssen".